# Escalante sbt plugin fails with missing org.apache.maven.wagon#wagon-provider-api;1.0!wagon-provider-api.jar

Tags: maven, sbt, escalante

I'm trying to get escalante-sbt running but without luck so far. I tried SBT 0.13.1 with Scala 2.10.3. Had the same issue as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351171/escalante-sbt-plugin-does-not-find-org-jboss-shrinkwrap-descriptorsshrinkwrap-d) and nothing worked for me. In my last attempt I cloned an [sbt-escalante example](https://github.com/arashi01/sbt-escalante-example) but not even this is working.

```
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#sbt-launch;0.13.1 ...
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] org.apache.maven.wagon#wagon-provider-api;1.0!wagon-provider-api.jar (1794ms)
[warn] ==== JBoss repository: tried
[warn]   http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-provider-api/1.0/wagon-provider-api-1.0.jar 
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.maven.wagon#wagon-provider-api;1.0!wagon-provider-api.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: download failed: org.apache.maven.wagon#wagon-provider-api;1.0!wagon-provider-api.jar
```

I would really like to get sbt-escalante working but I'm out of ideas. What is left to try?

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with the [Escalante SBT](https://github.com/escalante/sbt-escalante) plugin so please excuse mistakes. The following seemed to work for me.

**project/build.properties**

```
sbt.version=0.13.2-M3
```

**project/sbt-escalante.sbt** (I thought I'd change [the official *.scala approach](https://github.com/escalante/sbt-escalante#set-up-escalante-sbt-plugin-in-your-project) to *.sbt)

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "JBoss repository" at "http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/",
  "Project Odd repository" at "http://repository-projectodd.forge.cloudbees.com/upstream/"
)

lazy val plugins = project in file(".") dependsOn(sbtEscalante)

lazy val sbtEscalante = uri("git://github.com/escalante/sbt-escalante.git#0.2.0")
```

**build.sbt**

```
import io.escalante.sbt.EscalantePlugin._

escalanteSettings
```

With the files in place, I could run `escalante-version` and hence assumed it worked fine.

```
[sbt-escalante]> escalante-version
[info] 0.3.0
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't work for me. Back to `sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors#shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base;1.0.3.Final: not found`. Trying `sbt-escalante.git#0.1.2"`still gives `sbt.ResolveException: download failed: org.apache.maven.wagon#wagon-provider-api;1.0!wagon-provider-api.jar`

Comment: Can you check out the following thread? I'm not experiencing the issue so I can't replicate - https://groups.google.com/d/msg/liftweb/H-WR48BojSc/gL7QcEN0r48J.

Comment: Yes, I checked out the Escalante SBT plugin myself and compiled it but it didn't solve the dependency issue.

Comment: Can you add `libraryDependencies += "org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors" % "shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base" % "2.0.0-alpha-5"` to **project/sbt-escalante.sbt**? It should be: `lazy val plugins = project in file(".") dependsOn(sbtEscalante) settings(libraryDependencies += "org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors" % "shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base" % "2.0.0-alpha-5")`.

Comment: Added `settings(libraryDependencies += "org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors" % "shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base" % "2.0.0-alpha-5")` like you said but it doesn't compile: `sbt-escalante.sbt:8: error: not found: value settings
settings(libraryDependencies += "org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors" % "shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base" % "2.0.0-alpha-5")`. Without settings() it compiles but gives the `unresolved dependency: org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors#shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base;1.0.3.Final: not found`.